Expectation of the length of a random vector whose coordinates are uniformly distributed.
Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d and uniformly distributed in $(-a,a)$. What is the value of $$\mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+\ldots+X_n^2}\right)?$$
Does it have a closed form expression? Is the distribution computable?

This is possibly not explicit enough to calculate with, but if $R$ is your RV, $B_n(r)$ is an $n$-ball centred at $0$ and $I_n(a) = (-a,a)^n$ then $P(R\le r) = \mathop{vol}{B_n(r) \cap I_n(a)} / (2a)^n$

Will this work?
As the comment suggests, the CDF  is the volume of the intersection of a ball of radius $R$ centered at the origin  and a concentric cube.  This is the volume of the entire ball minus the volume of that portion of the ball that bulges outside the cube.
For simplicity consider the three-dimensional case.  Assume the cube is $[-1,1]^3$. Consider the nontrivial case $1<R<\sqrt{3}$ in which case the ball sticks outside the unit cube.  Consider e.g. the bulge that lies above the plane $z=1$.
The volume of the region that bulges out  can be expressed as the integral of cross-section slices: $\int _{z=1}^{z=R}A(z,R) dz$ where $A(z,R)=\pi (R^2-z^2)$ . (In other dimensions it may involve radicals.)
From the CDF and its derivative (which is in turn also an integral in the $z$ variable) you should be able to write the expected value integral as an explicit expression (in some dimensional cases as a double integral).

$\def\E{\mathbb{E}}\def\P{\mathbb{P}}$This doesn't answer the question (so maybe shouldn't be an answer), but we can get a pretty good asymptotic estimate as follows. I'll assume $a=1$; clearly the answer scales linearly with $a$.
We have $\E X_i^2 = \frac13$, so by standard concentration results such as Azuma-Hoeffding we have
$$ \P\Bigl( \bigl|\sum_1^nX_i^2 - \frac{n}3 \bigr| \ge d\Bigr) \le 2\exp(-d^2/2n) . $$
Thus $\sum_1^n X_i^2$ is strongly concentrated around $n/3$, so much so that $\E\sqrt{\sum_1^n X_i^2} = \sqrt{n/3}+O(1)$.
